# Converting DXF file to shapefile by exporting only certain fields using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, python

I have a problem converting multiple DXF files into shapefiles. In particular I use the script that is shown below for conveying multiple files. But the output shapefile is very large due to the number of attributes. I would like to be able to export only the Elevation field (I am interested only to points entities) in the shp file in output. But I cannot use the FieldMapping class effectively. I have an elementary knowledge of ArcPy.

What should I do?

```
import arcpy
import os    
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True
in_workspace    = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outFolder       = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
env.workspace   = in_workspace
datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets()
for dataset in datasets:
    filesets = arcpy.ListFiles(dataset)    
    for f in filesets:
        print f
        InPoint = os.path.join(env.workspace,f,"Point")    # the CAD points
        SaniF   = f.replace(" ","_").replace("-","_").replace(".","_")  # remove invalid chars..
        if int(arcpy.GetCount_management(InPoint).getOutput(0)) == 0:
            arcpy.AddWarning("- No points")
        else:
            outPointShape = '{}_Point.shp'.format(SaniF)
            arcpy.AddMessage('- Exporting Points')
            myfields = ['Elevation']
            mapS = arcpy.FieldMappings()
            for field in myfields:
                map = arcpy.FieldMap()
                map.addInputField(inPoint, field)
                mapS.addFieldMap(map)
            arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(InPoint,outFolder,outPointShape,"#", mapS)
```

Comment: I'd simply delete other fields after export.

Comment: Or populate a temporary file geodatabase feature class, which won't be subject to size limitations, the extract only what is needed.

Comment: for a dxf of 40mb I get a shp of 600mb because of the .dbf file. then deleting the fields takes a long time. for this I would like to be able to select the fields to be exported before the coversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you find point part of drawing, apply this:

```
destFC=r'C:\SCRATCH\abcd.dwg\Point'
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(destFC, "AB")
destFields=arcpy.ListFields("AB")
desc = arcpy.Describe("AB")
field_info = desc.fieldInfo
for i,f in enumerate(destFields):
    if f.name in ("FID","Shape","Elevation"):continue
    field_info.setVisible (i, "HIDDEN")
addLayer="TO_CALC"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(destFC, addLayer,"","",field_info)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(addLayer,"c:/scratch/points.shp")
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is the final script I used:

```
import arcpy
import os    
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True
in_workspace    = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outFolder       = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
env.workspace   = in_workspace
datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets()
for dataset in datasets:
    filesets = arcpy.ListFiles(dataset)    
    for f in filesets:
        print f
        InPoint = os.path.join(env.workspace,f,"Point")    # the CAD points
        SaniF   = f.replace(" ","_").replace("-","_").replace(".","_")  # remove invalid chars..

        if int(arcpy.GetCount_management(InPoint).getOutput(0)) == 0:
            arcpy.AddWarning("- No points")
        else:
            outPointShape = '{}_Point.shp'.format(SaniF)
            arcpy.AddMessage('- Exporting Points')
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(InPoint, "AB")
            destFields=arcpy.ListFields("AB")
            desc = arcpy.Describe("AB")
            field_info = desc.fieldInfo
            for i,f in enumerate(destFields):
                if f.name in ("FID","Shape","Elevation"):continue
                field_info.setVisible (i, "HIDDEN")
            addLayer="TO_CALC"
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(InPoint, addLayer,"","",field_info)
            arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(addLayer,outFolder,outPointShape)
```

Comment: The best way to say thank you here is accepting solution posted.